# Scatter plot labels in one line - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

It's possible to set all labels at once in Matplolib?

For example, I have this piece of code to plot a scatter plot:

```
cmap = plt.get_cmap('Set1')
colors = [cmap(i) for i in numpy.linspace(0, 1, simulations+1)]

plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
plt.scatter(coords[:, 0], coords[:, 1], marker='o', c=colors, s=50, edgecolor='None')
plt.legend(loc='lower left',)
```

where `simulations = 7` and `coords` is a numpy.array with shape (7, 2).

This gives me a plot like that:

[image]

If I change the last line for:

```
plt.scatter(coords[:, 0], coords[:, 1], marker='o', c=colors, s=50, edgecolor='None', label=range(simulations))
plt.legend(loc='lower left')
```

I get:

[image]

I'm wondering if I'll have to do a loop to do the scatter and set each label of if there is some way to do all at once.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do it with a scatter plot. But I'm not sure if there is an advantage to use `scatter` rather than `plot` if you want different labels.

How about this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 10
coords = np.random.random((n,2))

cmap = plt.get_cmap('Set1')

for i, (x, y) in enumerate(coords):
    plt.plot(x, y, 'o', color=cmap(i/float(n)), label='%i'%i, ms=9, mec='none')

plt.axis((-0.5, 1.5, -0.5, 1.5))
plt.legend(loc='lower left', numpoints=1, frameon=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]